# Not able to use conditional between integer data and string data

Tags: python

I am making a simple matchmaking program where the program will give the person the name of a boyfriend based on an input (age), but python is not accepting mixing integer variable data go along with string data

```
age = 40
boyfriend_1 = "John"
age_match = input("Say how old are you: ")
input("Say who would you like to date with: ")
if age_match > age:
    print: "tu novio será" +boyfriend_1
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Moderador/PycharmProjects/untitled/my first program.py", line 5, in 
    if age_match > age:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 1):

change to:

```
age_match = int(input("Say how old are you: "))
```

input results in a string that needs to be converted